# Parse.com: Performing "SELECT FROM - INSERT INTO" operations in Classes

Tags: sql, database, parse-platform

I'm making some changes in my Classes estructure in Parse.com (before migration to another own sever). I need to move masively information from one table to another:

1. I need to query information from User class
2. I must insert the result of step 1 in Vehicles class

If it were SQL, it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO Vehicles (veh_brand, veh_line, veh_model, veh_cap)
(SELECT veh_brand, veh_line, veh_model, veh_cap FROM User);
```

Is there a way to perform this operation? I'm not understanding weel Parse.com documentation. Where must i run this operation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Values` keyword

```
INSERT INTO Vehicles (veh_brand, veh_line, veh_model, veh_cap)
SELECT veh_brand, veh_line, veh_model, veh_cap FROM User
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've corrected that mistake. I'm looking to perform that operation in Parse.com